# Are booster shots for pets required annually to maintain rabies immunity?

Tags: zoology, vaccines

There are highly varied [state laws](http://vaccines.dogsadversereactions.com/files/RabiesLaws.pdf) and international laws regarding rabies vaccinations for pets - particularly regarding how frequently booster shots are required.

[This article in the NBC news](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/8572826/ns/health-pet_health/t/still-vaccinating-your-pet-every-year/#.VlX9FtCH6fQ) suggests that annual vaccinations are not necessary.

> with rabies vaccine, new data indicate the immunity lasts for at least seven years, she [veterinarian Jean Dodds] says.

Is there evidence that repeat vaccinations (after the initial inoculation series) are needed to prevent rabies in pets?

Comment: @Oddthinking: bold and beautiful, thanks for the edits :)

Answer (score 1):

When you take your dog to another country, the legal requirements are variable and depend both on target country legislation (*as indicated in your first link*) and the type of vaccination. In Europe the vaccination validity is 1, 2 or 3 years.

There are some studies on the duration of rabies vaccination, but limited to 3 years. Beyond that period, there is no evidence that the vaccination efficiency decreases.

> Sources:
>
> - "Are we vaccinating too much?" by R.D. Schultz,
> - "Current and future canine and feline vaccination programs" by Feline Medicine, 3 mai 1997, Montréal, Québec.
> - Dr Gary Norsworthy, conférence de l'Académie de Médecine Vétérinaire du Québec;
> - R. B. Wilson and others, "A neurological syndrome associated with the use of a canine coronavirus-parvovirus vaccine for dogs",
>     Compendium on Continuing Education for the Practicing Veterinarian,
>     vol. 8, 1996, p. 117-124.

From [Source1 (Schultz)](http://www.bogartsdaddy.com/bouvier/documents/effective_safe_vaccination_programs_by_rd-schultz.pdf)

> To ensure that all pups become immune, one dose of rabies vaccine is
>   given at 12 weeks of age or older, followed by a second dose 1 year
>   later, or at 1 year of age. Revaccination is then done at 3 year
>   intervals. Similarly the CPV-2, CDV and CAV vaccine could be given at
>   1 year and then every 3 to 5 years without concern about loss of
>   immunity. There is no evidence, or reason, to believe that
>   revaccination with the core vaccines more often than recommended above
>   would provide more effective protection from the important diseases
>   since the minimum duration of immunity from the core vaccines is at
>   least 3 years. States in the USA which require annual revaccination
>   for rabies should remove those requirements because annual
>   revaccinations are unnecessary.